# How to access NextJS buildid during build time?

Tags: next.js

I'm doing my first NextJS project, and currently looking at logging. Looking around, I found [this blog post](https://giancarlobuomprisco.com/next/how-to-build-production-grade-nextjs-projects), which suggests configuring Pino to log the commit SHA in each message. This makes sense to me for a lot of reasons. The question is, how do I get the SHA when Next is doing its static build? In the blog example, they're deploying on Vercel, and get it from there:

```
const logger = pino({
  base: {
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    revision: process.env.VERCEL_GITHUB_COMMIT_SHA,
  },
});
```

But I almost certainly will not be deploying on Vercel. Equally, there's lots of documentation on how to generate a custom build ID, which comes down to doing something like this in `next.config.js`:

```
const nextConfig = {
  generateBuildId: async () => {
    const buildId = await determineBuildId()
    console.log(`> Build ID: ${buildId}`)
    return buildId
  },
}
```

But I can't find any documentation on how to actually access the buildId within Next, so that it's a constant in my logging:

```
const logger = pino({
  base: {
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    revision: // how do I access the generated buildId here?
  },
});
```

This really must just be a failing of my google-fu, because this seems like it should be common practice, but ... I can't find it. Any ideas? Or pointers to documentation?